# Need help with CSS3

Tags: css

Ok here is the html and css3

```
<div id="sitename">
    <div class="logo">
    <a class="home" href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <span class="someclass"><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></span>
    <span class="recharger">Some text</span>
    <span class="reload">Some other text</span>
</div>

.reload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 181px;
    width: 140px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-duration: 400ms;
    -o-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition: opacity;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
??? {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

I want to make the text in .reload appear when I hover on .home (2 places). What should I replace the ??? with ?

Thank you

Comment: Can't think of a valid way of doing this with CSS (There might be but can't think of it) but have you thought about javascript. Very easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CSS you need to have the elements nested, e.g.:

```
<a class="home" ...><span class="reload">...</span></a>
```

Then you can use some CSS like this:

```
a.home:hover .reload { opacity: 1 !important; ... }
```

Otherwise you'll have to use JavaScript to sort this out.  You can easily do this in jQuery:

```
$('a.home').hover(function () {
  $('.reload').css('opacity',1);
  $('.reload').css('filter','alpha(opacity=100)');
});
```

Comment: Some minor notes: `.css()` can handle multiple property changes `$('.reload').css({'opacity':1,'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)');` and they do not have to be nested just *on-par* with each other ;)

Answer (score 1):

The closest to what you want is the general sibling combinator `~`, but the elements  (*`.home` and `.reload`*) have to be in the same nest level

*so **if** your html **was***

```
<div id="sitename">
    <a class="logo home" href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
    <a class="someclass home" href="#">Home</a>
    <span class="recharger">Some text</span>
    <span class="reload">Some other text</span>
</div>
```

the the appropriate css would be

```
.home:hover ~ .reload{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
```

---

quoting the [General sibling selector <sup>MDC reference</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

> The **`~`** combinator separates two
>   selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the
>   first, and both share a common parent.

Comment: @anothershrubery, i know.. just suggesting alternate routes if CSS is the only option ..

Comment: Haha, yeah I know I was just jesting!